# Java JBullet models not colliding

Tags: java, physics, models

Hello I wan't to do model collsion in JBullet but that don't won't to work. Models look like have some invisble holes.

Here the code for creating collsion shape:

```
int triangles_count = (int) ((mesh.getVertices().length) / 3);
    int vertices_count = (int) (mesh.getVertices().length);

    ByteBuffer index = BufferUtils.createByteBuffer(vertices_count * 3 * 4).order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    index.clear();
    for(int i=0; i < triangles_count; i++) {
        index.putInt(i);
    }

    ByteBuffer shape = BufferUtils.createByteBuffer(triangles_count * 3 * 4).order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    shape.clear();
    for(int i=0; i < triangles_count; i++) {
        shape.putFloat(mesh.getVertices()[i].getPos().x());
        shape.putFloat(mesh.getVertices()[i].getPos().y());
        shape.putFloat(mesh.getVertices()[i].getPos().z());
    }

    shape.rewind();
    index.rewind();

    TriangleIndexVertexArray triangle_mesh = new TriangleIndexVertexArray(triangles_count, index, 3 * 4, triangles_count, shape, 3 * 4);
    BvhTriangleMeshShape out_shape = new BvhTriangleMeshShape(triangle_mesh, true);

    return out_shape;
```

When I change first for loop to this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < vertices_count; i++)
```

I have exception  java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException produced in this line of code:

```
BvhTriangleMeshShape shape = new BvhTriangleMeshShape(trimesh, true);
```

Comment: You need to ensure that the sizes you are passing are correct. This applies to both createByteBuffer() and TriangleIndexVertexArray(). At least for indices `* 3` doesn't look correct.

Comment: How ever thanks I fix that problem. I use IndexedMesh and that starts working !